# Using sed/awk to remove anything after first space

Tags: sed, grep, awk

```
aaaaaaaa 09  
bbbbbbbb 90   
ccccccccccccccc  89  
ddddd 09
```

Using sed/awk/replace, in the above text I want to remove anything that comes after the first space in each line. For example the output will be:

```
aaaaaaaa  
bbbbbbbb    
ccccccccccccccc  
ddddd
```

any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 49):

Sed

```
sed 's/\s.*$//'
```

Grep

```
grep -o '^\S*'
```

Awk

```
awk '{print $1}'
```

As pointed out in the comments, `-o` isn't POSIX; however both GNU and BSD have it, so it should work for most people.

Also, `\s`/`\S` may not be on all systems, if yours doesn't recognize it you can use a literal space, or if you want space and tab, those in a bracket expression (`[...]`), or the `[[:blank:]]` character class (note that strictly speaking `\s` is equivalent to `[[:space:]]` and includes vertical spacing characters as well like CR, LF or VT which you probably don't care about).

The `awk`  one assumes the lines don't start with a blank character.

Answer (score 19):

```
cut -d ' ' -f 1 < your-file
```

would be the most efficient.

Comment: cut may be the best solution for problems this simple.  I would reserve awk (or perl) for more complex matching.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Looking at the man-page for `cut`, I can't tell if it will accept any sort of regex syntax. Do you have any idea whether or not it will, and if so, which type(s)? sry to bother and thanks.

Comment: @NateT, no only single characters and with several implementations, even limited to singe byte characters only.

Answer (score 6):

```
awk '{print $1}' file
```

or

```
sed 's/ .*//'
```

Answer (score 1):

And the one through `perl`,

```
$ perl -pe 's/^([^ ]+) .*$/\1/' file
aaaaaaaa
bbbbbbbb
ccccccccccccccc
ddddd
```

Through GNU grep,

```
$ grep -oP '^[^ ]*' file
bbbbbbbb
ccccccccccccccc
ddddd
```