# Delete string file after space

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I have many log files generated like the bellow:

```
Date;Time;Brand;User;Node;Location
01/01/01;666;blabla;George Armani;Springfield
```

I want to delete the String ***Armani*** but my command is not working:

```
cat file.log | grep identifier | cut -d ";" -f | sort | uniq | grep -o '^\S*' > newfile.log
```

I'm following the next [post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/98983/using-sed-awk-to-remove-anything-after-first-space)

Is the another way to make it?

PS. There are strings in the same field with different length.

Comment: Why did you add `grep identifier` to your pipeline?

Comment: None of the commands in the pipeline seem to align with your stated aim of removing a string after a space - if you want to delete from the space up to the next `;` delimiter that can be as simple as `sed 's/ [^;]*//' file.log`

Comment: @Jesse_b I invoke the grep "Identifier" because that lines  contains the fields that I want to delete.

Comment: @Mareyes: I don't see the string "identifier" in your sample input at all

Comment: @Jesse_b The identifier can be any field in the file. Thre's not be specific one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `awk`:

```
awk -F\; 'OFS = ";"{ if ($4 ~ " "); split($4, fname, / /); $4=fname[1]; print }' input
```

This will split the 4th column by whitespace and then set it to the first element.

---

Should work regardless of what is in the 4th column:

```
$ cat input
Date;Time;Brand;User;Node;Location
01/01/01;666;blabla;George Armani;Springfield
02/02/02;777;blabla;Jesse_b;South Park
03/03/03;888;blabla;test name;somewhere

$ awk -F\; 'OFS = ";"{ if ($4 ~ " "); split($4, fname, / /); $4=fname[1]; print }' input
Date;Time;Brand;User;Node;Location
01/01/01;666;blabla;George;Springfield
02/02/02;777;blabla;Jesse_b;South Park
03/03/03;888;blabla;test;somewhere
```

Comment: This is the only answer one I needed, only I have a doubt... "fname" is the field name?? In this case "Node"? Edit: I obtain the same fields.

Comment: fname is just a variable to hold the split string (In this case I was thinking first name)

Comment: Dude, it works. Thank you! I'll study more about awk, is powerfull tool!

Answer (score 1):

To delete the text 'Armani' from the file, use this:

```
$ sed 's/Armani//' myfile
Date;Time;Brand;User;Node;Location
01/01/01;666;blabla;George ;Springfield
$
```

To edit it inplace:

```
$ sed -i 's/Armani//' myfile
$ cat myfile
Date;Time;Brand;User;Node;Location
01/01/01;666;blabla;George ;Springfield
$
```

If you want to delete *all* occurrences of 'Armani' within a single line, add a `g`, e.g. `sed 's/Armani//g'`

Answer (score 1):

The cat is pointless so that can go.
Identifier is not in your sample input so let's assume you meant blabla.
Your request to delete the users last name seems completely unrelated to your example command so let's just change that

```
grep blabla file.log | perl -pe 's/ [^ ;]+;/;/g' > newfile.log
```

If that does not give you what you want you should rewrite your question so that it is clear.